# IdP initiated saml recieved on SP always has RelayState as null

Tags: saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have been tasked to implement a `SAML2.0 SSO` proof of concept and I have successfully integrated the `spring saml` extension which has been pretty straightforward, thanks to the author. Although, I still haven't been able to get the `RelayState` parameter to work, I always get its value as `null` on the receiving `SP`.

I am using `SSOCircle's` public `IdP` with an `IdP` initiated flow (although we have not blocked the SP initiated mode) and appending the `RelayState` in the [URL](https://idp.ssocircle.com/sso/hos/AdPage.jsp?returnUrl=/sso/saml2/jsp/idpSSOInit.jsp&metaAlias=/publicidp&spEntityID=myUniqueEntity&RelayState=/successurl).

I am trying to use the `SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler` where I could get the `RelayState` parameter from the `SAMLCredential` instance but its always `null`. I traced it back to the `HTTPPostDecoder.doDecode(MessageContext messageContext)` method (HTTP post binding) and it was null there as well. I also traced the browser network url and noticed the SP consumer end point post url i.e. `/saml/SSO` contains `SAMLResponse` but there is no `RelayState` parameter (my understanding is it will be a separate parameter).

I feel the `IdP` is probably not sending the `RelayState` to my SP but also don't see any configuration on the `IdP` side to enable/disable it so not sure.

I would appreciate advice on debugging this or if someone could share their similar experiences.

Comment: Please provide a network trace with the flow of the http requests. That is the best way to verify the RelayState is passed by the IDP.

Comment: @hos My apologies to reply this late and thanks a lot for your reply. Without any reply for over 15 days I had given up and did not monitor updates. One more reason why I may have not monitored later is that after my development, I had moved to Pre-prod with a different IDP (I developed against the public IDP ssocircle). It worked smoothly at the new IDP so I assumed the issue was with ssocircle and not my code. In fact,just recently I realized the ssocircle IDP too started working,not sure if they put in some fix.The network trace by the way did not carry the RelayState when posting to my SP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I donot have this issue any more but did not explicitly add any fix either. My best guess is ssocircle put in a fix on their end after which the RelayState url started flowing end to end for me.
Appreciate the help by @hos. Did not want to keep the question open so add this as an answer.